# What (exactly) does a GSM module do

Tags: gsm, cellphone

What (exactly) does a GSM module do?

I know that it connects whatever it's wired to to a GSM network, but what is its role? Does it just relay the dial tones to the network or does it actually interpret the tones and then send the call out?

Trying to make a rotary dial cell phone...

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: GSM is digital, it doesn't use 'dial tones'.

Comment: The spec sheet for the GSM module should expain it's operation and expected inputs/outputs.

Comment: I know, but I just want to know how the GSM module places the call. The phone sends it the dial tones from the keypad, then what.

Comment: The way you word your question hints that you don't have the faintest idea what is going on. Explaining (exactly) what a GSM module doesw would require a few years of university level study. And dial tones don't appear in it. If you want to connect a rotary dial phone to a GSM module you must study a GSM module interface document, and learn to program a microcontroller.

Comment: What documents have you read so far? Please read the [help] to learn how to ask good questions that get good answers. We avoid answering general questions that already have good answers, which available to anyone who puts the effort in to use a search engine. We usually expect people to ask more specific questions than 'how does a GSM module work'. I think you could find explanations using a web search, and then reading a few documents.  Then asking more specific questions here.

Comment: In terms of an easy hack, it could be relatively straightforward to interface a pulse-to-DTMF circuit to an existing phone. Hand-waving over the phone particulars and encoding/decoding design, of course. But no knowledge of GSM (or telephony at all, really) is necessary to simply add a layer of pulse encoding to a handset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GSM module is a radio modem.  It's the 'business end' of a cell phone, stripped of the user interface (microphone, speaker, keypad, display, etc.).  It connects to a cell network through one of the supported cell frequencies.  Creating and maintaining a cell network connection is an extremely complex process that involves detecting the cell towers, negotiating with them, establishing a connection, handing off to adjacent cells at the appropriate time, changing modulation formats on the fly depending on the signal to noise ratio, changing transmit power based on commands from the cell tower, etc.  You can get entire books that cover bits and pieces of what goes in to a GSM modem, not to mention the rest of the cell network.

The GSM modem does not speak in dial tones.  To establish a call, a command containing the phone number would be sent to the GSM modem over a digital interface.  The GSM modem would then send a request over the GSM control channel to the currently associated base station.  Then the base station would assign a data channel to use and start the process of connecting the call.  Once connected, the GSM modem would use that data channel to transmit and receive audio data in digital format, and the cell network would route that data to the other end of the connection - be it another cell phone, the 'standard' phone network (PSTN), etc.

What you're going to have to do is use a microcontroller to interface the rotary dial to the GSM modem control interface.  You'll have to write some code to detect when the phone is taken off the hook and which numbers are dialed, then send the proper commands to the GSM module to connect the call.

Answer (score 0):

the GSM module is a kind of data modem, you will need to convert the voice to and from GSM audio data, the dial pulses to GSM modem commands.
and the status codes from the modem to dial-tones and ringer activity etc...

It's probably easier to just buy a GSM FXS adaptor and plug the phone in.